# How can I capture a URL from Chrome Custom Tabs without clicks?

Tags: facebook, authentication, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

I am trying to switch to CustomTabs from WebViews as it has been disabled by Facebook for login. For this, I need to get the access token from the URL in the custom tab. How can I do this without requiring the user to click somewhere?

Comment: I didn't know Facebook had disabled WebViews. Do you have a link for an announcement? Or, do you know when this change happened?

Comment: Yes, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/deprecating-webviews

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook login SDK already uses Custom Tabs under the hood. There are docs on how to use it in your application here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/

In order to implement this manually, you need to create an Activity that has intent-filter that uses a custom schema and use that schema as the redirect URL for the OAuth flow. There's a sample that implements this flow for the GitHub OAuth here https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/tree/main/demos/custom-tabs-oauth.

Comment: But Facebook only allows URIs with the HTTPS scheme to be used as valid OAuth redirect URIs.

Comment: Their docs point out to the following as the protocol scheme: 
<string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb649326238470013</string>. Is it the case you can't change this on their configuration UI?

Comment: Additionally, it's possible to implement this with an HTTPs scheme, as long as you implement Digital Asset Links for the origin (the demo on GitHub actually uses HTTPs https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/blob/main/demos/custom-tabs-oauth/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)